# Importing web service with Core Data or SQLite or something else?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I'm creating an Events app which needs to pull data from a JSON web service to get information about the artists and the shows that are being played. The data will be used to display the line up of artists (a to z) on one view, artists by date and time on another view, and artists by location and sorted by date/time on a third view.  We will also allow the user to add shows to their schedule.

The JSON data is similar to this:

Artists feed:

```
[
{
"artists": {
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Kendrick Lamar",
        "subtitle": null,
        "imageURL":
"//goevent-images.s3.amazonaws.com/.../web/artist_3_20140331112744_d57b5a70.jpg",
                "gcInfo": "artist$kendrick-lamar/3",
"shows": [ {
                        "id": 153,
                        "venueTitle": "Sapporo scene",
                        "formattedDate": "Sunday, August 31",
                        "date": "2014-08-31",
      "title": "Kendrick Lamar"
                    }
                ],
                "tags": ",8,159,164,",
                "color": "#00a0a0",
                "dates": [
                    "2014-08-31"
                ]
},... },
]
```

Shows feed:

```
[
{

"items": {
        "197": {
                "id": 197,
                "title": "Arcade Fire",
                "type": "artist",
                "dateStart": "2014-08-30",
                "timeStart": "16:00:00",
                "formattedTimeStart": " 4:00 PM",
                "gcInfo": "artist$arcade-fire/127",
                "venueId": "1",
                "tags": ",80,",
                "color": "#337FC3"
}
}
]
```

Shows and artists will have a many to many relationship. I'll also need to create an entity/table for storing the user's shows that will be added to their personal schedule.

Bands/shows do have the possibility of being removed from the feed, so I think I'll likely need to clear out the artists and shows entities/tables before importing. I'm worried this will break the relationship to the user's scheduled shows.

I also need to download as much of the high-level data as possible upfront so that the app can be used offline as well.

So my question is:
What's the best approach to importing and storing the data for this?

Answer (score 1):

“Best” is subjective.  As I understand it, Core Data uses SQLite under the covers, so it's really more a matter of what you're comfortable with.

Have you used Core Data before?  If so, use that.

Have you used an SQL Database before?  if so, use SQLite.

If you're starting from square one, I supposed I'd recommend Core Data.

Here are a few links to get you started:

1. [Data Management in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html) by Apple
2. [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) from Apple.
3. [Core Data Tutorial for iOS: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)
4. [How to Use SQLite to Manage Data in iOS Apps](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)
5. [SQLite Tutorial for iOS: Creating and Scripting](http://www.raywenderlich.com/902/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-creating-and-scripting)